# What is the popup called that appears lower left when you manipulate a mesh?

Tags: edit-mode

What is the name of this pop out?  It only appears when you start changing the shape of a mesh.

[image: edit-popout]

Answer (score 4):

It's called an ["Adjust Last Operation Panel"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/regions.html). You can also see the name directly in the UI.

[image]

Sometimes it's also referred to as the "Operator Panel" in online discussions, however many panels in Blender's UI have operators, which makes this term ambiguous.