# Bring up the operation panel

Tags: modeling, properties, panel

How do you bring up the operations panel for an object after accidentally clicking into the 3D View? For example when you bring in an cylinder you can set its properties i.e. the number of vertices radius, depth etc. but if you click, it disappears. How can you bring it back up when you need it again?

Comment: Just for reference, the panel is actually called Adjust Last Operation Panel. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146403/what-is-the-popup-called-that-appears-lower-left-when-you-manipulate-a-mesh/146406#146406

Answer (score 1):

You can access it either through <kbd>F9</kbd> or *Edit > Adjust Last Operation*.