# How can I get this info box to show me what my exact changes were?

Tags: interface

In blender versions before 2.8, whenever you made a change you would be presented with this:

[image]

How can I get this in 2.8?

Comment: See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146950/bring-up-the-operation-panel and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146403/what-is-the-popup-called-that-appears-lower-left-when-you-manipulate-a-mesh/146406#146406

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what to call it, so I couldn't look it up.